# video to audio file convert & save through FFMPEG in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am working on an FFMPEG on node js. I'd like to retrieve the audio track from a video file using node js. I would also like to save such file but I can't figure out how.

I though this line of code would help me :

```
ffmpeg('/path/to/file.avi').noVideo();
```

I have got this in npm package. I don't quite understand how to work with this and how to actually save the audio file.

Some other line of code that come in play :

```
try {
    var process = new ffmpeg('/path/to/your_movie.avi');
    process.then(function (video) {
        // Callback mode
        video.fnExtractSoundToMP3('/path/to/your_audio_file.mp3', function (error, file) {
            if (!error)
                console.log('Audio file: ' + file);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.msg);
}
```

My question is:

**How do I retrieve the audio from a FFMPEG video ? How do I save it ?**

Comment: You wanna `demux` the video.. This seperates the audio, subtitles and video from eachtoher.. With ffmpeg the command would be : `ffmpeg -i file.avi -acodec copy -vn file.ac3` -> Assuming AC3 is the audio codec ofc course!~

Comment: But I want to do this with node js

Comment: This question deserves an upvote

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would do it like:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
/**
 *    input - string, path of input file
 *    output - string, path of output file
 *    callback - function, node-style callback fn (error, result)        
 */
function convert(input, output, callback) {
    ffmpeg(input)
        .output(output)
        .on('end', function() {                    
            console.log('conversion ended');
            callback(null);
        }).on('error', function(err){
            console.log('error: ', e.code, e.msg);
            callback(err);
        }).run();
}

convert('./df.mp4', './output.mp3', function(err){
   if(!err) {
       console.log('conversion complete');
       //...

   }
});
```

just make sure `ffmpeg` is installed and is part of system path, also make sure all the necessary codes are present.

**Update:**

for video without audio, simply do `.noAudio().videoCodec('copy')`:

```
function copyWitoutAudio(input, output, callback) {
    ffmpeg(input)
        .output(output)
        .noAudio().videoCodec('copy')
        .on('end', function() {                    
            console.log('conversion ended');
            callback(null);
        }).on('error', function(err){
            console.log('error: ', err);
            callback(err);
        }).run();
}
```

---

**Update 2:**

for merging video and audio into single:

```
function mergeMedia(aud, vid, output, callback) {
    ffmpeg()
        .input(aud)
        .input(vid)
        .output(output)
        .outputOptions(
          '-strict', '-2',
          '-map', '0:0',
          '-map', '1:0'
        ).on('end', function() {                    
            console.log('conversion ended');
            callback(null);
        }).on('error', function(err){
            console.log('error: ', err);
            callback(err);
        }).run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. This can create audio mp3 file. But how can I create a video without audio & save it file.mp4 ? Can you please help me ?

Comment: Thanks... you are just awesome. Thanks for you help. I want to meet you in facebook. Can you give me facebook id ? Thanks

Comment: Can you please help me to add a mp3 audio with a video which has no sound ?? I want to make this ffmpeg in node js.

Comment: I have done this . But I have faced some problem. If my audio is longer then video how can i remove extra audio ?

Comment: try adding `'-shortest'` to the outputOptions

Comment: Can you please help me too add effects like grayscale in whole video & also other video effects in video by ffmpeg in node js ?

Comment: #mido22 can you please help me to give effect in video??? You can answer me in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910430/how-to-give-effects-in-video-by-ffmpeg-in-node-js

Comment: while merging video and audio into single, remember to add audio codec as well. Eg: .audioCodec('libmp3lame')