# S3 Video to audio file convert using Node js (Lambda function)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert S3 video file to audio file through Lambda function. Whenever video files are uploaded into an S3 bucket I have to generate an audio file and save it back to S3 bucket by triggering the AWS Lambda function. I can convert the video file to audio in local. ( [Convert video to an audio file using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842316/video-to-audio-file-convert-save-through-ffmpeg-in-node-js)). But I am wondering, how to do this conversion part in Lambda function every time the video file is uploaded into an S3 bucket. I have no idea how to do this AWS Lambda function. Please share your suggestions.

**Sample code:**

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
/**
 *    input - string, path of input file
 *    output - string, path of output file
 *    callback - function, node-style callback fn (error, result)        
 */
function convert(input, output, callback) {
    ffmpeg(input)
        .output(output)
        .on('end', function() {                    
            console.log('conversion ended');
            callback(null);
        }).on('error', function(err){
            console.log('error: ', e.code, e.msg);
            callback(err);
        }).run();
}

convert('./df.mp4', './output.mp3', function(err){
  if(!err) {
      console.log('conversion complete');
      //...

  }
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: May also be worth considering Elastic Transcoder if you have large video files. See https://medium.com/@ratulbasak93/video-to-audio-using-elastic-transcoder-lambda-with-sns-notification-cdc8ba8a6e78

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set up an event on s3 bucket - put object - to trigger lambda function (you will get access to the description of the object uploaded to that S3 bucket through the first parameter of the lambda function).

If you can convert the video file to audio on your local machine, using some external libraries, then you need to create a zip file containing your lambda function (in the root of the zip file) as well as the dependencies.

This is pretty simple in case of Node. Create a new folder, run `npm init`, install needed modules, create index.js file where you put your Node code. Zip all the contents of this folder (not the folder itself). When you create new lambda function, choose to upload this zip file.

If you are wondering about how to programatically communicate with AWS resources and manipulate them, then check `aws-sdk` which you can import as a module and use it for that purpose.

So basically what you will need to inside of your lambda function is to parse `event` argument (the first parameter) to obtain bucket and key of the uploaded object. Then you will call `s3.getObject` method to get the data. Process the data with your custom logic. Call `s3.putObject` to store the newly transformed data to new S3 location.

Lambda has access to its own local file system, if your code needs to store some data there. You just need to specify absolute path to the file, such as `/tmp/output.mp3`. To retrieve it, you can use `fs` module. Then, you can continue with `s3.putObject`.

Comment: Yeah, we can get an s3 object by triggering a lambda function. But after converting into an audio file how to upload that audio file into an s3 bucket. If you look at the above code the function gets input and output path. how to do this in lambda function? thanks.

Comment: @Arun Lambda function has access to its own local file system. You don't need to modify your code. Once the process is done and file is stored in that local fs, you can retrieve it using `fs` module and then upload it to S3.

Comment: I think it's generally better to use s3:ObjectCreated:* rather than s3:ObjectCreated:Put to trigger the Lambda.