# Download billboard hot 100 (but only 50) mp3 files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, youtube, screen-scraping

Yo yo yo. I got this insane idea to get 50 of the billboard hot 100 songs, download them into mp3 files, and then put them on private online radio.

Problem is, the way I do it doesn't download each file one by one, it puts all the music together in one mp3 file. Here's my code so far (terrible, I know... I just wanna throw this together really quickly)

```js
const { getChart } = require("billboard-top-100");
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
const { mkdir } = require("fs");
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const YT = require("scrape-youtube").default;

getChart('hot-100', (err, chart) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    chart.songs.length = 50;
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.songs.length; i++) {
        var song = chart.songs[i];
        song.artist = song.artist.replace("Featuring", "feat.");
        var name = `${song.artist} - ${song.title}`;
        YT.search(name).then(res => {
            downloadVideo(res.videos[0].link, name).then(_ => { console.log(""); }).catch(console.log);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    };
});

function downloadVideo(url, name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var stream = ytdl(url, { filter: "audioonly", quality: "highestaudio" });
        var start = Date.now();

        ffmpeg(stream)
            .audioBitrate(128)
            .save(`${__dirname}/${new Date().getWeek()}/${name}.mp3`)
            .on("end", _ => {
                console.log(`Downloaded "${name}.mp3" - Took ${(Date.now() - start) / 1000} seconds.`);
                resolve(`${name}.mp3`);
            })
            .on("error", _ => reject("something went wong"));
    });
}

Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
  return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can try look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30857972/1101930. You can try using the output() function. The docs of ffmpeg having multiple approaches of saving

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.save()` & `.output()` is the same.

Comment: Not most likely, but i think it can have something to do with the order of the chaining functions when calling ffmpeg. You save something before it ends, wether the stream is finished or not. Try using save function at last of the ffmpeg chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by using a forEach method instead of a regular for loop.